# appframework app.ready not fired

Tags: appframework

I am currently using appframework MVC for mobile devices, the problem is that app.ready is not fired on android devices, but working fine on IOS devices.
Any suggestion, below is my little code:

```
var app = new $.mvc.app();
app.loadModels("login");
app.loadControllers("login");
app.ready(function() {
    alert("I am at the app ready");
    $.mvc.route("/login");//Load the default login route
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After this, you have to throw ui

```
$ui.launch();
```